# Lasinfo like task with lascatalog lidR

Tags: lidr

I would like to have an idea about the classification of point clouds loaded in a `LAScatalog` with lidR. With a las file, I can do this way:

```
library(lidR)
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
las <- readLAS(LASfile)
table(las$Classification)
```

How can I perform such queries with `LAScatalog`?

Comment: You have to read the files to get these information. They are not stored in the header and are thus not accessible in a `LAScatalog`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to read the files to get these information. The header of a las file does not store a summary of the classification. Consequently a LAScatalog cannot access such information because it only reads the headers. You can loop through your files:

```r
lapply(files, function(file) {
  las <- readLAS(files, select = "c")
  table(las$Classification)
})
```